# how to find largest number in 2d arraylist of different datatypes for specific column?by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to find the largest number in 2d array list of different data types for a specific column?by using python.
Okay I know this looks really simple, but I'm stuck here :(

hers is the question if the image URL is not opening.

```
            [['NAME', ['A','B','C','D','E']],
             ['A', [41,34,45,55,63]],
             ['R', [42,34,45,55,63]],
             ['L', [32,23,13,54,67]],
             ['G', [23,82,23,63,34]],
             ['P', [21,23,25,56,56]]
           ]
```

how to find the largest score in column B?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What have you done so far and what is not working?

Comment: Sir,i just want to know  how can I find the largest number in the 2nd column of 2d-arraylist of different data type? Asking for  the above arraylist .that i have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way to change your data into pandas dataframe:

```py
data = [['NAME', ['A','B','C','D','E']],
             ['A', [41,34,45,55,63]],
             ['R', [42,34,45,55,63]],
             ['L', [32,23,13,54,67]],
             ['G', [23,82,23,63,34]],
             ['P', [21,23,25,56,56]]
           ]


temp = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    row = []
    row.append(data[i][0])
    for j in range(len(data[i][1])):
        row.append(data[i][1][j])
    temp.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(temp[1:], columns=temp[0])
```

Now you can use `df['B'].max()` to get the max score on column B.

Comment: Thank you sir, this could really help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the max() method or function idk. I haven't programmed with python for a while now.

Here you get a list:

```
l = []
for o in range(len(data) - 1):
    l.append(max(data[o + 1][1]))
print(l)
----------------------
[63, 63, 67, 82, 56]
```

Edit:

```
list = [['NAME', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']],
        ['A', [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
        ['R', [42, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
        ['L', [32, 23, 13, 54, 67]],
        ['G', [23, 82, 23, 63, 34]],
        ['P', [21, 23, 25, 56, 56]]
        ]

a = list[1][1]
r = list[2][1]
l = list[3][1]
g = list[4][1]
p = list[5][1]
```

You could do:

```
asort = max(a)
rsort = max(r)
lsort = max(l)
gsort = max(g)
psort = max(p)
```

```
Outputs:
63
63
67
82
56
```

Its not nice, but I think you can understand this. I hope.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But how can I find the  largest number in the 2nd column of 2d-arraylist of different variables?

Comment: added it in my post. I  hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you again sir, It is really helpful.